# Ballistic with friction - what is wrong with my reasoning?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, projectile

I consider a **ballistics problem with friction**:

[image]

Here is a graphical representation of it:

[image]

I know from the textbook that **the solution is**:

[image]

Which is **different from what I found**. **Here was my reasoning**:

[image]

So my question is: **what is wrong with my reasoning please**?

Comment: I think you that  a’ is not correct

Comment: @Eli Thanks. Why so please?

Comment: $\begin{aligned}a=-\dfrac {1}{\tau }y'-g\\
a'=-\dfrac {1}{\tau }y''\end{aligned}$

Comment: @Eli Ok, but line 5 I set a=y''. So can you explain what you mean please?

Comment: But in line 6 you redefined a?

Comment: @Eli ... to be equal to y'', yes. Don't get me wrong: I also think a' is perhaps not correct... I just don't know why.

Comment: Make this transformation $\begin{aligned}a=y'
a'=y''\end{aligned}
$ to get the right result